# Pypi package not installing on some systems

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypi

I have created a python package, which I uploaded to pipy using the following commands:

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
twine upload dist/*
```

And the `setup.py` is:

```
import setuptools
with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
     name='pakk',  
     version='0.3',
     scripts=['pakk.py'] ,
     author="**insert Author**",
     author_email="some_email@mail.ru",
     description="pakk",
     long_description=long_description,
     long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
     url="https://some_website.nice",
     packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
     classifiers=[
         "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
         "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
         "Operating System :: OS Independent",
     ],
 )
```

It is all working good on my Windows 10 machine, but in other places it does not.
For example:

1. In google colab after doing the following

```
!pip install pakk
import pakk
```

I get the error:

```
Collecting pakk
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/aa/70/23a20ee172f26903ffc47b18e56c7274e078ecc4f5251e77f3f0/pakk-0.3-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pakk
Successfully installed pakk-0.3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-111-7f093c9bb12b> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install pakk')
      2 
----> 3 import pakk

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pakk'
```

Although it is present in `pip list` and even in cache in this example.

2. On [repl.it](https://repl.it) the module does not even install, it freezes at

```
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals

  - Installing pakk(0.3)
```

What could be the reason? And how do I fix it?
In both of these websites, I have never encountered such errors. Also, I am not sure that dependencies are recognized and installed, but I can write them by hand anytime.

Comment: The code does not simply prints some text. It downloads some Python code from a URL and executes it (`exec()`), which is quite suspicious.

Comment: @sinoroc sorry about that, the code in the link gust prints the text, you can check if you want. I was just testing...

Comment: Fair enough, but what happens if a few months from now, this URL hosts malware code instead of just _print_ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the distributions from PyPI to inspect them.

There are no packages that `find_packages()` could find. Additionally there are no `py_modules` in `setup.py`. So there is nothing to import.

The `statsmodelier.py` module is added as `scripts`, so it is definitely not added as a importable module. If it is supposed to be an importable module then it should be added to `py_modules` instead of `scripts`.

Comment: But how do I add it as  ```py_modules```? And how do I add modules to ```setup.py```? Do I just import them there?

Comment: Somehow the _setuptools_ documentation doesn't show it, but it's the same as distutils in that case: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-individual-modules

Comment: Okay, and what about adding it as ```py_modules```?

Comment: Oh, I got it. I just write it instead of ```scripts``` and drop the ```.py```